# Append-Method gives back a '-' instead of space if used as select-statement

Tags: c#, append

I have a several strings, which i want to append to use it as a statement:

```
string tableToSelect = "COUNT(Table) as Table";

StringBuilder sqlQuery = new StringBuilder();

sqlQuery.Append("SELECT Month,");
sqlQuery.Append(tableToSelect);
sqlQuery.Append(" from ");
sqlQuery.Append("tbl_TEST");
```

If I copy-paste the result into SQL Server Management Studio it gives me following:

> SELECT Month, COUNT(Table)-as-Table from tbl_TEST

Any ideas?

Comment: The `StringBuilder` does not change the characters, as the string `" from "` is still in tact. What type is `tableToSelect`? Does the result contain the differences or do they only show up in management studio?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis tableToSelect is a string, it's declared on the first line.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis What do you mean with "is still in tact"? Sorry, tableToSelect is of type string. The result shows up only like this in management studio.

Comment: @Bridge My fault, edited my post after his comment.

Comment: @Jendrik I meant if the problem was caused by the StringBuilder, it would also change " from " to "-from-". But you already mentioned the 'problem' only exists in management studio. I don't think this question has anything to do with [c#] or the Append method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be fine; thoughts:

- are you sure those are regular spaces in your local copy, and not some other whitespace unicode character?
- is any other code tweaking the query before executing it?

.NET will not invent dashes.

> If I copy-paste the result into SQL Server Management Studio

and from where *exactly* are you copying? (since you haven't even called `sqlQuery.ToString()` yet).

Comment: Thanks your post brought me to the fix. Somehow i copy-pasted "COUNT(Table) as Table" with some invisible '-' letters. After rewriting it manuelly, my problem was fixed!

Comment: @Jendrik the simplest option is usually a good place to start ;p If they don't look like spaces, then they probably *aren't spaces*.

Answer (score 0):

No - no idea, but why don't you do it this way:

```
string.Format("SELECT Month, {0} FROM tbl_TEST", tableToSelect)
```

What does the debuger give you as output?
Try to copy/past it first into edit.exe and then copy it there and past it into SQL Managment Studio.